# Getting Data back from Push_back

Tags: c++, opencv

I copied some images to a vector in c++. Now I need the same mats in some place. How I will get my data back from push_back. Please help me out. Here is the part of the code......

```
for (ic = 0; ic < images.size(); ic++) 
     {
         roi_b.x = images[ic].x;
         roi_b.y = images[ic].y;
         roi_b.width = (images[ic].width);
         roi_b.height = (images[ic].height);
         crop = image(roi_b);
         Ims.push_back(crop);   //Ims<vector>
}
```

Now let suppose I need back data stored at ims. How i will get that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::vector::back()`.

```
crop = Ims.back();
```

If you want to enumerate through `Ims`, you can do

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < Ims.size(); ++i)
    crop = Ims[i];
```

and do what you want on `crop`.

Comment: with crop=ims.back() i am just getting the last image not all

Comment: @kkdirvi Please be more specific on what you want to get.

Comment: timrau......Let I copied image1 and image2  to a Mat images with Push_back(). Size of each image let be 64x64. Now I needed to copy these two images to a single Mat of size 128x128.....My question is clear now I think

Comment: @kkdirvi Edited on how to go through all those elements. On how to fill a 128x128 matrix with 2 64x64 matrices, it depends on your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `at()` function or the overloaded `operator[]` to access the members of the vector an any index.  If you want the last element then you can use `back()`.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can use at or overloaded operator?

Comment: @kkdirvi: you would just do `Ims.at(some_index)` or `Ims[some_index]` like an array.